# Check if xml exists in a directory and read it

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I'm new to c#. I want to read an xml file if it exists in a directory. 1) How can I read it? 2) If there are multiple xml files how to read those at the same time?

```
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(path)
        string pathD = @"H:\UsersDirectory";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] TXTFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
        if (TXTFiles.Length != 0)
        {
            //how can I read the file?
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [FileInfo.OpenRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.openread?view=net-6.0), [XMLDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-6.0) and [XmlDocument.Load(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmldocument-load(system-io-stream))

Comment: You want to use following with a Search Pattern "*.xml" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0  The use a for loop to open each file foreach(string file in TXTFiles){ StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);}

Comment: And of course a [basic course on loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/csharp-101/csharp-what-are-loops) won't do any harm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to be [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the file, you can use:

```
File.Exists("YourPath");
```

to check if the File exists. If not, you can use:

```
Directory.GetFiles("ContainingDirectory");
```

to get a list of all files in a directory, and then loop through them, checking if they end with .xml, to find your file.

As for reading the content of the file, you can use

```
File.ReadAllText("FilePath");
```

to read the content of your XML-File. For multiple files, you can obviously just call this function multiple times, once for every file.

If you want to edit XML too, I'd like to direct you towards XPathNavigator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/xml-xpathnavigator